# Why when remote debug is not active my user is null and when its active its an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When I'm using the debug js remotely my user is **not** null and when I'm not using the debug js remotely my user is null. 
Here is my code to check if the user is logged in and then directing him to the correct component:

```
componentDidMount(){
that=this;
this.authSubscription = firebaseRef.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
  firebaseRef.database().ref('/users/'+user.uid+'/info').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
      that.setState({
        haveInfo: true,
        loading: false,
        user: true,
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        user: true,
        haveInfo: false,
      })
    }
  });
  }else{
  that.setState({
  user: false,
  haveInfo: false,
  loading: false,
 });
}
});
}

render() {
if (this.state.loading) {
  //Welcome screen
  return <Welcome />
 }

if (this.state.user) {
    if (this.state.haveInfo) {
      //the user set up his info
      return <Main />
      }else{
      //If the user didnt set up his info
      return <ProfileSettingUp />
     }
  }

// If the user is null
return <MainLogToSignUpProceses />
```

}

I don't know why this is happening. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't directly answer your question from your code however, you should be aware that when you enable the remote js debugging you are using the browser's JS runtime instead of the mobile one. So there could be a missing function or a different implementation in these two runtimes.

Please refer to this article for more info: [You should not always rely on remote debugging (React Native)](https://medium.com/@suyogkrazz/you-should-not-always-rely-on-remote-debugging-react-native-787a850c7ad8)

Comment: Glad to help! Also, try turning off remote debugging from time to time and see if something breaks suddenly.

Comment: I will do that for sure! Thanks.

Comment: T.sagiv I am having the same problem did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue too.